# Using Jquery-Raty with Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, raty

I am trying to add star ratings populated by a field in my database in a template rendered callback. I believe the problem is that raty can not find the images but I've had trouble getting it to work. The images are currently in App/public/img and the raty code in the callback is:

```
Template.game.rendered = function() {
$('.game-rating').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    numberMax : 5,
    path: App/public/img,
    score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-score');
    },
    starOff: 'star-off.png',
    starOn: 'star-on.png'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try path:/img  The public folder in Meteor is seen as /

You may also need to quote it.  path:'/img',

Comment: Dang still nothing. just cant get the images to come up.